# How to stop Jetbrains Rider opening sidepanel on ALT-9 on macOS

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, rider

Suddenly JetBrain Rider opens the Repository side panel on <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>.

This is very inconvenient as <kbd>ALT</kbd> keys are for special characters on macOS. In my case <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> is for `}` so anytime I want to insert an closing `}` the repository sidebar opens.

I could not find any suspicious entries in the Keymap preferences.

I'm pretty sure this wasn't the case yesterday but I have made no conscious changes to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Keymap and try to remove/change the key assigned to the tool windows:

[image: VCS keymap]